# how do you call a flat file via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to execute an ajax call to a txt file and read it every 5 minutes. I have the below code to execute a php script:

```
function webserver_cpu_Data() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'shell.php', 
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    seriesOptions=data;
                    createChart();
            setTimeout(webserver_cpu_Data, 600000); 
                },
                cache: false    
                });
        }
```

Is there a way to read a file  like txt.file though and ajax call?

I have creted this function to call a php script to display values.

```
function myAjax() {
       var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
    $.ajax({ url: 'echo_file.php', success: function(data) {
    seriesOptions=data;
    createChart();
    }
    });
    }
```

I am doing this to run the above function for every 5 minutes:

```
setInterval(function() { myAjax(); }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

I dont get any values back. However this works. The idea is to get the below into an ajax call.

```
var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],

        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
        $.getJSON('test.txt',   function(data) {

            seriesOptions= data;
            createChart();  
        });
```

Comment: If the flat file is in the server then you can access it by its url just like the php file.

Comment: assuming the name of the file is test.txt, I just set url: 'test.txt'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following will work if your file is JSON encoded (for example, it was returned to the client using `echo(json_encode($array))` in the PHP file:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'php_file_returning_json.php', success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

This will only work if the content-type is set to JSON. The PHP file will need this header at the top of the file:

```
header("content-type: application/json");
```

Otherwise, you will need to `JSON.parse(res)` the data in the success function.

To call it every five minutes, this would be as simple as:

```
setInterval(function() { myAjaxFunction(); }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I've update my post. I am not getting the results from the ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The point you're looking for is 'datatype'. Change it to 'text' and it should run smoothly.</strike>

EDIT: You requested a txt-file so I gave you one, JSON however is an entirely different story.

jQuery has this horrible behaviour to silently cancel a JSON ajax call if the JSON isn't valid, a problem I'm sure has already cost thousands of hours wasted time looking anywhere but the JSON response, which was my problem at least twice and is most likely also yours.

What you need to do is validate the JSON that you're getting from the php, if you can get the plain data you can paste it into [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: I did that not working. The data in my test.txt file is json format. I just need to read this file via ajax call every 5 minutes.